# date format with inconsistant data Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am have a freetext column which a date is input to.

is there a way i can force the output to display the same?

for example some people are entering '2/12/15' others are entering '02/12/2015'

how i can i get the output to pick up the dates and change them to a consistant format?

no idea where to start. I have tried "To_char" but it says 'invalid number'

Comment: Show some examples of the exact data you have to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I believe you want `to_date( )`:

```
select to_date('2/12/15', 'mm/dd/rrrr') 
from dual;
```

The 'rrrr' for year will format the year correctly.  See date formats here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm

Comment: @lee tyler - Just make sure you are handling ALL possible date formats. The real solution is to validate the data at the point of data entry to make the users enter it correctly in the first place, and into a date datatype - if that is within your scope of control.

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach here may be to use a PL/SQL function that accepts the string and then attempts a series of date conversions on it with different date format pictures ('DD/MM/YY', 'DD/MM/YYYY' etc) until it finds one that does not raise an exception.

This won't work if some people enter DD/MM/YYYY and others enter MM/DD/YYYY, but will appear to in some cases.